# FOSRestBundle - Having a single resource both standalone and nested as a child of another

Tags: symfony, api-design, fosrestbundle

I'm working on a Symfony API using FOSRestBundle. I am currently dealing with two entities;

`Client` Which has a one-to-many relationship to `Project`.

Both of these entities are working fine as standalone resources (see the following `debug:router` output)

[image]

I've started looking at [nesting resources](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/6-automatic-route-generation_multiple-restful-controllers.html) (i.e. having `Project` as a child resource to `Client` and have updated the routing as follows;

```
clients:
  type: rest
  resource: bdd.controller.client

projects:
  type: rest
  parent: clients # newly added
  resource: bdd.controller.project
```

This works (to a degree) however I now end up with the following routes;

[image]

Accessing `/clients/1/project` calls `ProjectController::getProjectAction()` (attempting to retrieve the Project with the ID of 1. Is this the intended behaviour now that `Project` is a child resource? And if so, would `Project` need to be added as a standalone resource again (duplicating the `projects` route key and removing `parent`) to retrieve a single project by ID?

Also, is there a reason that the `get_client_projects` route has singular-ified `client`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing issue you're seeing is because your `get` actions in your `ProjectController` are missing the parent's argument. Update your getter's method definition to be `getProjectsAction($clientId, $id)` and the routes should update to what you expect.